# SonarQube Analyze project dependencies with Gradle

Tags: gradle, sonarqube

I have multiple projects in which one project is a dependency for another.
Let's assume, there are 3 gradle projects

- Proj A
- Proj B
- Proj C

Inside Proj A , I mentioned my dependencies as

```
depndencies{
  compile project(':Proj B') - Path mentioned in settings.gradle
  compile project(':Proj C')
}
```

So, If i run the gradlew of ProjA all my dependent projects also gets buid.

Similarly, I have a Sonarqube plugin in my Proj A. The moment I run gradlew sonaqube. It goes to proj B and says

## {package in ProjB} should be relative to project baseDir

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `<projectName>.sonar.projectBaseDir` properties, example:

```
ProjB.sonar.projectBaseDir=/home/user/projB
ProjC.sonar.projectBaseDir=/home/user/projC
```

Read more about [Analysis Parameters](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters).